# Enumerate BOOLs from an NSDictionary

Tags: xcode, plist, nsdictionary, enumeration, boolean

I have a .plist file that is loaded into my Xcode project. I have successfully put it in the documents directory of my iPhone while testing it. When I dump the contents into an NSMutableDictionary, and try to enumerate it, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes. They keys all have BOOLs associated as their values. What am I doing wrong?

My code now:

```
for (id key in achDict) {

    NSLog(@"Achievement:%@ done:%@", key, [[achDict objectForKey:key] boolValue]);

}
```

This always returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NSLog is expecting two objects but you are passing it a string 'key' and an Integer. A Bool Value is not an Object, it returns an Integer value (0 for False and 1 for True). `%@` is for Objective C Objects. Instead use `%d` to get Integer Values such as C Booleans.

Change your NSLog statement to:

```
NSLog(@"Achievement:%@ done:%d", key, [[achDict objectForKey:key] boolValue]);
```

Apple's [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) has a useful section on String Modifiers

Comment: While this DOES work, it returns 1s and 0s. I need it to return explicitly YESs and NOs (or TRUEs and FALSEs). Is there any way to display a boolean value in an NSLog?

Comment: You could use an inline conditional and have something like: `NSLog(@"Achievement:%@ done:%@", key, (([[achDict objectForKey:key] boolValue]) ? @"True" : @"False"));`